# In scons call a custom function using builder

Tags: scons

I have a custom function which I want to call using builder object

```
def generate_action(target, source, env):
    print "TRIDIP:::::::I am in"
    return None
```

Now I created a builder

```
env['BUILDERS']['generateAction'] = Builder(action = generate_action)
action = env.generateAction()
```

As you see, I have not pass any arugument and I don't want to pass any argument for which my custom function generate_action() is not called. I want to call the function without any argument.

Comment: SCons is a file-oriented build system, so which file do you want to create with your Builder action? If your answer is "none", then you probably don't need to make it a method of the Builder object. Define and call your "generate_action" without any parameters and you should be fine, right?

Comment: Well, the reason I add the custom function "generate_action" in the builder object is because I want to call my custom function in build time and also this function depends on other build result. This is the reason I add in a builder object .

Comment: @dirkbaechle I don't have any file to create with builder action . The reason I add the custom function "generate_action" in the builder object is because I want to call my custom function in build time and also this function depends on other build result. This is the reason I add in a builder object .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the Builder, specifying the result file you depend on as source. You can't leave the "target=" *and* "source=" parameters out at the same time, because SCons has to know where in the total build graph this step fits in. Your SConscript should look something like (untested, and from the top of my head):

```
# env = Environment()
env['BUILDERS']['generateAction'] = Builder(action = generate_action)
# creates your other result file
myResult = env.someOtherBuilder('out.foo', 'in.txt')
# calls your generate_action method
action = env.generateAction('dummy.txt', myResult)
```

Note, how this will *always* call your "generateAction" Builder, because the "dummy.txt" is never created, so the target is never up-to-date.

Finally, my guess is that this answer won't really help and lead you into more trouble. When people try to call custom methods at build time they're usually using SCons in a wrong way...most of the time because they don't have the correct mental model to understand how SCons works. You might want to read up on some basics in the UserGuide ( http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html ) or ask your further questions on our User mailing list at `scons-users@scons.org` (see also http://scons.org/lists.php ).

Comment: Yes, I need to pass a dummy file 'dummy.txt' to call the custom function. Thanks for your answer.